# Problemas con helper de Razor generando un campo de texto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

es mi primera vez en esta comunidad, y tengo poco tiempo usando RAZOR. Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy generando un campo de tipo texto en mi vista cshtml y necesito que los atributos "name" y "id" de mi  no sean diferentes.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, "Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10"> 
                @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" name="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" onblur="completarCodigo()" value="@ViewBag.cliente"/>*@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onBlur = "completarCodigo()", @value = "@ViewBag.cliente" } })               
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $("#OCRDSAPF2_CardName").autocomplete({
                            source: function (request, response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '@Url.Action("getClientes", "Cotizacions")',
                                    data: { term: $("#OCRDSAPF2_CardName").val() },
                                    datatype: "json",
                                    success: function (result) {
                                        response(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
                    <strong>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, "", new { @class = "bg-danger" })
                    </strong>
                </div>
        </div>
```

el código HTML que me genera es:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="ERROR:El campo Cliente no puede estar vacio." id="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" name="OCRDSAPF2.CardName" onblur="completarCodigo()" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

y lo que deseo es que sea:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line ui-autocomplete-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="ERROR:El campo Cliente no puede estar vacio." id="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" name="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" onblur="completarCodigo()" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Trata sobreescribiendo la propiedad name:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OCRDSAPF2.CardName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onBlur = "completarCodigo()", @value = "@ViewBag.cliente", Name="OCRDSAPF2_CardName" } })
```